# How do I prevent showing a:first while on setInterval()

Tags: jquery

I'm facing two problems

1) I used the following code to hide all elements but to show only `.ticker a:first`

```
$.each($('.ticker a'), function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('.ticker a:first').show();
});
```

This works but the problem is whenever I use the function below to animate ticker it shows up the `.ticker a:first` again.

```
function ticker(){
    $.each($('.ticker a'), function(){
        $(this).slideUp();
    });
    $('.ticker a:first').slideUp(function() {
        $(this).appendTo($('.ticker')).slideDown();
    });

}
setInterval(ticker, 2000);
```

2) While animating the `.wrapper` div flickers while `slideDown()`. How can I prevent that?

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RXCZ/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is not good:

```
$.each($('.ticker a'), function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('.ticker a:first').show();
});
```

What you want instead is this:

```
$('.ticker a').hide().filter(':first').show();
```

For the ticker function itself:

```
function ticker(){
    $('.ticker a').first().appendTo($('.ticker')).slideUp().end().end()
                  .filter(':first-child').slideDown();
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RXCZ/1/)**.